# Getting "ORA-06413: Connection not open." in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have setup a new rails application ( Ruby 2.4.0 and Rails 5.0.2 ) . When I launch the application after starting rails server , it generates an error "ORA-06413: Connection not open" . I am using ruby-oci8 (2.2.3) and activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) and oracle client ( 10.1.0 ) . I have also set ORACLE_HOME , LD_LIBRARY_PATH , TNS_ADMIN environment variables in .bash_profile . I am getting below error snap shot ;

ORA-06413: Connection not open.

Rails.root: /home/akhand/work_space/test_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

oci8.c:654:in oci8lib_240.so
ruby-oci8 (2.2.3) lib/oci8/oci8.rb:142:in `initialize'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:346:in`new'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:346:in `new_connection'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:405:in`initialize'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:24:in `new'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:24:in`initialize'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:8:in `new'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/connection.rb:8:in`create'
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.7.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:169:in `oracle_enhanced_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:729:in`new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:773:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:752:in`try_to_checkout_new_connection'

Content of my database.yml is below ;

## Development DB

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  username: test
  password: secret
  database: test_dev:9102/testdb
```

## Test DB

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%=RAILS_ENV%>.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000
```

## Prod DB

```
production:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  username: test
  password: secret
  database: test_dev:9102/testdb
```

I have tried several solutions that I found in google search but none of them worked for me . Any help will be greatly appreciated . Let me know if any other information is needed .

![Rails_Error][1]

Comment: By default the oracle listener runs on port 1521, or did you change it? Maybe this can help: https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced#database-connection

Comment: Also the connect string should be `//hostname:port/service_name` where service name != database name. Service name is defined in your `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris :-)

Comment: I have also tried double slash before host name but it didn't work ;

database: //test_dev:9102/testdb 

My oracle application listens at 9102 port actually . In service name I am providing SID of the database . But still facing issues . And I had also gone through the link and tried the tricks provided there but still no luck .

Comment: could you share content of `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: Sure . Below is the entry for this database in tnsnames.ora file ;

newoasisdev.world =
 (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = test_dev)(PORT = 9102))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = testdb)
    )
  )

Comment: Please ignore the last database.yml that I had earlier shared . Correct content is below ;

sqlite: &sqlite
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/<%=RAILS_ENV%>.sqlite3
  timeout: 5000

oracle-dev1: &oracle-dev1
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  username: test
  password: secret
  database: test_dev:9102/testdb

oracle-prod: &oracle-prod
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  username: test
  password: secret
  database: test_dev:9102/testdb

development:
  <<: *oracle-dev1

test:
  <<: *sqlite

production:
  <<: *oracle-prod

Comment: Could this be the issue? http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/solution-for-ora-6413-error-showinh-connection-not-open/ Turns out there is a bug in oracle client because of parentheses in path name

Comment: There are no parentheses in the path of my application . Application path is /home/akhand/work_space/test_app

Comment: it's not about you project workspace but installation of oracle client

Comment: You mean path of oracle client ? Path of Oracle client on my linux server is

/oraunix/app/oracle/product/10.1.0

Comment: Is your os 64 bits? Make sure you also have installed 64bit oracle client.

Comment: Yes , os as well as oracle client both are 64 bit .

Comment: Sorry out of options currently, any luck yet?

Comment: Yes . I had resolved the issue by installing oracle instant client 12.2 . When I went through the library files of oracle_enhanced from where error was being generated , there was a version check and this error was being generated because oracle server version was 12.x.x and oracle client that I was using was 10.x.x . So, I installed the oracle client 12.2 and issue is resolved now .